# Why does query return no results

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I am trying to write a SQL query to fulfil the below requirements. All the naming conventions are correct for the tables, columns, and values. Yet my query does not return anything.

- Check if the `SpecializationCode` exists in the `Specialization` table. If it does not exist, insert the `SpecializationCode` and `SpecializationName` into the `Specialization` table
- Insert doctor details into the `Doctor` table
- Insert the newly generated `DoctorID` and the given `SpecializationCode` into `DoctorSpecialization` table with `SpecializationDate` as current date

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_AddDoctorDetails
    (@DoctorName VARCHAR(25),
     @SpecializationCode CHAR(3),  
     @SpecializationName VARCHAR(20))
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @DoctorID INT
    
    SELECT @DoctorID = DoctorID 
    FROM Doctor 
    WHERE DoctorName = @DoctorName

    BEGIN TRY
        IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT SpecializationCode FROM Specialization 
                       WHERE @SpecializationCode = SpecializationCode)
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO Specialization (SpecializationCode, SpecializationName)
            VALUES (@SpecializationCode, @SpecializationName)

            INSERT INTO Doctor (DoctorID, DoctorName)
            VALUES (@DoctorID, @DoctorName)
 
            INSERT INTO DoctorSpecialization (DoctorID, SpecializationCode, SpecializationDate)
            VALUES (@DoctorID, @SpecializationCode, GETDATE())

            RETURN -1
        END
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        RETURN -99
    END CATCH
END
GO
```

Comment: I don't get it: if `Doctor` row exists, you will get a PK violation. if it does not exist then `@DoctorId` will be null and PK cannot be null. What are you trying to do with `Doctor` table? If you remove the `TRY/CATCH` you will see exactly what error is happening

Comment: You are eating the error. Don't catch an error and do nothing with it. The caller must know if an error occurs. Is DoctorName enforced as a unique key / constraint in Doctor? If not, your logic is very flawed. Is SpecializationCode a primary key in Specialization and a foreign key in Doctor? If not, you have more schema problems.

Answer (score -1):

Replace `Return -1` with `SELECT 1 / 0 AS Error;` in `TRY` Block
Replace `Return -99` with
`ERROR_LINE() AS ErrorLine,`
`ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage;` in `CATCH` Block

Your procedure look like this after changes with only TRY CATCH block

```
 BEGIN try 
      IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT specializationcode 
                     FROM   specialization 
                     WHERE  @SpecializationCode = specializationcode) 
        BEGIN 
            INSERT INTO specialization 
                        (specializationcode, 
                         specializationname) 
            VALUES     (@SpecializationCode, 
                        @SpecializationName) 

            INSERT INTO doctor 
                        (doctorid, 
                         doctorname) 
            VALUES     (@DoctorID, 
                        @DoctorName) 

            INSERT INTO doctorspecialization 
                        (doctorid, 
                         specializationcode, 
                         specializationdate) 
            VALUES     (@DoctorID, 
                        @SpecializationCode, 
                        Getdate()) 

            SELECT
             1 / 0 AS Error; 
        END 
  END try 

  BEGIN catch 
    SELECT 
        ERROR_LINE() AS ErrorLine,
        ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage;
  END catch
```

Comment: No - don't eat the error and return the error information as a regular resultset.